# What is the purpose of the D4 diode between base and emitter of PNP transistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, bjt, npn, pnp

I am having problem with understanding the purpose of the Q7 transistor. [image: PNP].

[image: PNP2]The anode of the D4 diode is connected to the base and cathode - to the emitter which makes Veb = -0.7V. This will always make the PNP transistor be on the OFF mode no matter what the base voltage is. It seems that if I remove Q7 transistor nothing will be affected and the rest of the circuit will work just same. However, it is not. When I remove it the whole circuit stops working properly.
Could anyone explain to me what I am missing here. Thank you

Comment: Your circuit is almost certainly drawn wrong. Much wider context and more circuitry would help. Knowing where the emitter connects to may help. If the pulse was -ve going may make somesense.a few more resistors seem likely. ||| More Detail!!!

Comment: I have added a better image of the circuit

Comment: We need even more details, just show the complete circuit because as shown, the circuit does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: It looks as if Q7's purpose may be to speed up discharging the gate capacitance of Q8, in order to make it switch off faster. But one can only tell for sure with more circuit context.

Comment: @NicatAli Cripes. That addition makes all the difference. Q7 is vital. During the short downward transition of the 12V-0V input on the left, Q7 very much is needed to sharpen the off-switch of the FET! It literally ***yanks*** the gate downward. (Another reason I don't like FETs. Oh, well.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment but there is not much useful information in the rest of the circuit. The base of Q7 transistor connected to either Mosfet driving Gate Pulse signal or 12V DC voltage. and R32 is connected to GND. The problem is in any case the Emitter voltage will be lower than the base voltage resulting in PNP transistor be OFF. Therefore removing PNP transistor should not affect the working of the whole circuit.

Comment: @NicatAli When the source drives towards zero, the PNP emitter is left still attached to the gate voltage (the BAT70 is reverse-biased then.) Which biases the Vbe many-times over it's normal forward bias. This immediately pinches the collector and emitter together and that fact discharges the gate-source charge very quickly. I don't see how you don't see this. (That said, I still don't see where that 22k goes.) (And I still hate MOSFETs.)

Comment: @jonk I didnt see your first comment. Thank you sooo much. It helped a lot

Comment: @NicatAli Thanks for letting me know it gets through to you. Stupid MOSFETs are like this. They require all kinds of obscure, sometimes difficult to recognize, aspects to make them behave. Worse, their \$g_m\$ stinks being squared-law devices. And at least as discrete components, they are nearly useless as analog signal amplifiers. Their Vgs is all over the map, so to speak. I'll take a BJT any day of the week over a FET. Except in a few very useful cases. (I'm speaking only as a hobbyist using discrete components. Not as an IC designer.) (Okay, there are dual-gate FETs that are interesting.)

Comment: @jonk, you typed all that on a computer made out of billions of FETs :-D We're surrounded by the little swines...

Comment: @jonk yeah I was only concentrated on Q7 and D4 so I missed that the gate of the Q8 is also connected to the emitter and its voltage is higher than the base voltage during the transision. Thanks again to all of you :)

Comment: @TonyM Yeah. I admit I'm waist-high in IC-FET swine-muck. I need shoulder-high waders to try and stay clean. ;) But I just can't abide the darned things in discrete designs. They annoy me. Static charges are a pain. Spice doesn't conserve charge, not even close. There's no valid FET model for it. So Spice will tell me "All is okay" when it's not even close to okay. It's an entire art-form, almost. And less of a science. At least BJTs need a continuous supply of recombination current. Spice handles that very nicely, almost without thinking. And so does a pencil on a piece of paper. Darned FETs.

Comment: @TonyM Spice uses the Meyer capacitance model for MOSFETs. You might hope there's a way to derive a set of charge relations for each terminal, such that the derivative of these charges will actually match up with the Meyer capacitances that Spice uses. Unfortunately, that is not possible. The Meyer capacitances are, by definition, incomplete and inconsistent. So no charge functions exist, when differentiated, that can give the Meyer capacitances. As a result, Spice and MOSFET models are fundamentally incompatible, so far as I am aware. I dislike the darned things (discretely.)

Comment: BTW, the symbol you are using for D5 is the symbol for a Schottky diode, not a Zener.  It's easy to confuse the two. Zener diode symbols have slanted "hands".

Comment: @jonk, we all know FETs have great overall advantages but I do completely see your points, well-explained as usual. There's an IBM 7070 in the post, if you're out they'll leave a 12 ton box with 14,000 boards and 60 KB at next-door's.

Comment: @TonyM FETs almost make themselves. Start with a P or N doped wafer and expose it to air (oxygen.) You'll get a layer of glass forming right away and given time, enough thickness. Or heat it up to make that a little faster. Then just lay a piece of aluminum on top and you've got yourself one of those silly FET things. They almost happen by accident. Lilienfeld proposed them in '26, for gosh sake. It's a wonder someone didn't trip over one before that. I love boards I can solder without a 20X magnifying glass and where I can *see* my bits -- love core memory!! (Sneezes don't mix with 0204s.)

Comment: @jonk, when I started out, resistors were fairly big things I could see, with coloured bands on that you could hook scope probes on. Then they went SMD and so small I could just see the numbers on them. Then smaller and I couldn't see the numbers. Then smaller and there was no space for numbers. Now so small I can't see the resistor as it might just be a track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

The postive pulses via the two parts of D4 drive the FET gate on.

In the absence of positive drive Q7 & R31 drive the FET gate off.

The transistor provides far more current drive than a pull-down resistor would, and so ensures far faster turn off, and draws minimal current when positive drive pulses are applied.

---

**FET turn on:** When a positive pulse is applied Q7 is turned off as its base is driven to about -0.6V relative to its emitter. The FET is driven on by the postive pulse via D4.

**FET turn off:**  When the positive pulse is removed (either open circuit or grounded) then Q7 emitter is at V_gate and it's base is pulled to close to ground via R31. V_r31 will be about (Vgate- Vbe_Q7)/R31 or for VGate = say about 11V early on, (11-0.6)/10k or about 1 mA.
For a [BC856](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11207.pdf) the beta (current gain) at 100 mA colletor current is about 100 so the ~= 1 mA base drive will drive it into saturation.
Vce can drop to about 0.1 - 0.2 V  with adequate base drive BUT as
the base drive is provided by Vcb it will probably end up at around Vce = 0.5V ultimately and at somewhere under 1V reasonably rapidly.

The [IRFZ44V](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44vzpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b60f62219) MOSFET has a Vgs_on of 2V min & 4V max, so the under 1V Vbe level achieved by Q7 is enough to turn and hold it off.

IRFZ44V has a gate charge of 65 nano-Coulomb max so at 100 mA discharge it will be discharged in about 700 ns.
However, discharge rate will drop as Vgate drops providing less V_R31 andf so less base current so turnoff time will probably be *in the order* of 1 microsecond.

Decreasing R31 will increase gate capacitance discharge time up to the capacity of Q7.  A [BC807-40](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC807_BC807W_BC327.pdf) would give usually faster gate switching times (if needed) due to higher beta and higher current rating.

---

D5 acts to damp gate oscillations by clamping negative Vgs ringing excursions. It should be mounted physically as close to the FET g-s leads as possible.

If inductive loads are being switched an extremely useful addition is a reverse biased Vgs connected zener (in parallel with D5 and also close to the FET g s leads physically) with a zener voltage rating slightly above Vgate-drive_max. The zener serves to clamp Miller capacitance coupled drain spikes from the inductive load and greatly improves the survival of the FET.